# Rails API - Mobile app status text error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a mobile application connected to a Rails server.

When I try to modify an `Item` in my Rails database from my application with a JSON request, I get an error message the first time the ajax request is made.

```
{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}
```

with

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'xxx',
    type: 'PUT',
    data: item,
    dateType: 'json'
    success: (response) ->
    error: (response) ->
      alert JSON.stringify(response) # {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}
```

If I check my Rails log, the server the action `PUT` for the given controller is not called.

My browser then automatically **reloads**. Now, if  I try to modify the item, everything is working...

Do you have any idea why?

**EDIT**

Every single other action call to my Rails API (other than `PUT`) succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this post](http://www.justinball.com/2013/02/25/jqxhr-returning-readystate-0-and-status-0/), I found the answer :

> Your Ajax request was triggered via a form submit or clicking on a link and you didn't call e.preventDefault() inside of your event handler. The browser will go ahead and submit the form or follow the link and execute your Ajax code. The form submit or the link follow will win and the browser will immediately terminate your request and give you back a readyState 0.

Adding `e.preventDefault` prevents the form from being submitted (submit = refresh because I am using a one page template).